# Запятая перед ИЛИ

Tags: или, пунктуация

Почему в этом предложение нужна запятая перед ИЛИ?

> Северо-западные склоны занимали
> черноспинные чайки, или, как их
> по-другому называют, кайры.

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед союзом или ставится запятая, если союз "или" употребляется в значении "то есть". Хрестоматийный пример: "В зоопарке жил бегемот, или гиппопотам".

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!:)

Answer (score 0):

Да, нужна, это присоединительный союз, который присоединяет обособленное приложение пояснительного характера. Здесь нет выбора "или-или".

Comment: И Вам Спасибо большущее за помощь!:)